# ASM 5.2 ClassReader.accept throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:2

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception, java-bytecode-asm

I am now trying to figure this Error our since a few hours and I have literally no idea what could cause it. I am trying to inject code into a class File.
The weird thing is that the injection works fine for ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS, but throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if I use ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES. And I need to use COMPUTE_FRAMES in order to run the edited Class. I am using asm 5.2 and found only out so far that COMPUTE_FRAMES  has a value of 2 (maybe this helps you somehow)

My Code:

```
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("Paht/To/Class.class");
    ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader(in);
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES){
        @Override
        protected String getCommonSuperClass(final String type1, final String type2){
            return "java/lang/Object";
        }
    };

    ClassVisitor mcw = new ModifierClassWriter(Opcodes.ASM5, cw);
    classReader.accept(mcw, 0);

    File outputDir = new File("Path/To/Output/dir");
    outputDir.mkdirs();
    DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(outputDir, "NameOfFile.class")));
    dout.write(cw.toByteArray());
    dout.close();
```

Modifier Method Writer:

```
    public static class ModifierMethodWriter extends MethodVisitor{

    private String methodName;

    public ModifierMethodWriter(int api, MethodVisitor mv, String methodName) {
        super(api, mv);
        this.methodName = methodName;
    }
    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
        super.visitCode();
    //InjectCodeHere, removed it because it most likely doesnt cause the error
    }
}
```

ModifierClassWriter:

```
    public static class ModifierClassWriter extends ClassVisitor{
    private int api;
    public ModifierClassWriter(int api, ClassWriter cv) {
        super(api, cv);
        this.api = api;
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv =  super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        ModifierMethodWriter mvw = new ModifierMethodWriter(api, mv, name);
        return mvw;
    }
}
```

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.Frame.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
at package.main.ClassMaker.main(ClassMaker.java:28)
```

Comment: You should get the source from ASM's SVN isntead of using their compiled jar. It will let you see the full stack-trace without names like `a` or `b`. As for the issue itself, frame generation tends to fail when a modification you make results in invalid bytecode. `//InjectCodeHere, removed it because it most likely doesnt cause the error` This is actually likely what has caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @display-name I found the error.

```
super.visitMaxs(4, 2);
```

in "ModifierMethodWriter" caused the error, the code which I actually didn't show here.